# What is the Scala classpath?

Tags: java, scala, jar, classpath

I've been trying to use a jar called `PasswordHash.jar` in my project. I am using `sbt`, so I put the jar in `lib/`. Now it is in the classpath, but I don't know what that means.

I've tried:

- `import PasswordHash`
- `import PasswordHash.jar`
- `import com.PasswordHash`
- `import com.PasswordHash.jar`
- `import org.PasswordHash`
- `import org.PasswordHash.jar`
- `import java.PasswordHash`
- `import java.PasswordHash.jar`
- `import jar.PasswordHash`

The jar was built from a Java file which didn't have a `package` statement.

EDIT:

Scala file:

```
~/FileShare/shared/src/main/scala/com/michael/fileshare/shared/Collatz.scala

package com.michael.fileshare.shared
import  com.michael.fileshare.shared.PasswordHash
```

Java file:

```
~/FileShare/shared/src/main/java/com/michael/fileshare/shared/PasswordHash.java

package com.michael.fileshare.shared
```

Error message:
`object PasswordHash is not a member of package com.michael.fileshare.shared`

The Scala file unsuccessfully tries to import the Java file, but a different Scala file successfully imports this Scala file.

If it helps, I'm on Ubuntu focal.

Comment: Not having a package is a really bad idea. Also, if you build the **Jar** from a single **java** class. Why not just adding that single source file to your project?

Comment: I tried adding the Java file too, but it didn't work. What do you mean not having a package?

Comment: Why adding the **Java** file didn't work? where did you added? which error did you get? - I mean that having source files which do not specify a `package` and including them into a **jar** is a bad idea, because it may cause troubles like the one you are having.

Answer (score 5):

`import foo.bar.x;` means something very very simple:

"In this source file, any time any mention of a type is just `x`, assume it reads `foo.bar.x`", **and that is all it means**. It doesn't mean that a file is loaded from disk when the import statement is 'run' (in fact, an import statement isn't "run" at all), and it is a literal no-op if you never mention x.

In scala it's mostly the same, though stuff like implicits are processed IIRC.

All your `import x.jar` statements are definitely wrong, `import` is not how you do that, at all. You just name type shortcuts, that's all that does. The job of locating the class file with the representation of that type is **not part of your source file** - it's part of the build, i.e., the arguments passed to javac or scalac.

### Okay, what's the solution?

you've made multiple errors here. The first one is that package-less classes **cannot be imported at all**. You **MUST** have a package declaration.

The second is that the class file must then be in the classpath as you compile your scala file. The rule for class path is as follows: Each entry in a classpath is either a directory or a jar file. Then, packages follow directories.

So, if you have:

```
import com.foo.PassHash;

public class Example {
    PassHash hash = new PassHash();
}
```

and your classpath is, say: `javac -cp whatever/x.jar Example.java`, then `whatever/x.jar` must exist, must be a jar file (or directory), and within that jar file or directory, there needs to be a directory named `com`, containing a directory named `foo`, containing a file named `PassHash.class`. Once you have that, the above will compile fine, and it's analogous in scala.